# how to write a TXT file on JavaCC?

Tags: java, javac, filewriter, javacc, printstream

I need to write a file TXT using the syntax of Tokens on JavaCC

Eample: (My Code..)

```
PARSER_BEGIN(ExaF)
import java.io.*;

public class ExaF
{
    public static void main( String[] args )throws ParseException
    {
        try
        {
            ExaF analizador = new ExaF( System.in ) ;
            An.Prog();
            System.out.println("\n\n All Ok"); 
        }
        catch(ParseException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("\n\n Problem...");
        }
    }
}
PARSER_END(ExaF)

TOKEN:
{
      <GAT: "#" >   {System.out.print("00 ");}
    | <FIN: ";" >   {System.out.print("01 ");}
    | <LLA: "{" >   {System.out.print("02 ");}
    | <LLC: "}" >   {System.out.print("03 ");}
}
```

But i need some like this:

```
TOKEN:
{
      <GAT: "#" >   {tex.write("00 ");}
    | <FIN: ";" >   {tex.write("01 ");}
    | <LLA: "{" >   {tex.write("02 ");}
    | <LLC: "}" >   {tex.write("03 ");}
}
```

I try...

```
PrintStream stext;
stext = new PrintStream(new File("3S.txt"));
stext.print("00 ");
```

and...

```
File sfile=new File("3S.txt");
FileWriter texto = new FileWriter(sfile,true);
texto.write("00 ");
texto.close();
```

Any idea???
JavaCC says:

**javac:821: error: cannot find simbol *stext.print("00 ")*;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since stext is used in the token manager you should declare it as follows

```
TOKEN_MGR_DECLS: {
 PrintStream stext = new PrintStream(new File("3S.txt"));
}
```

Having done that, you will be able to use stext in token actions.  Consult the documentation at https://javacc.java.net/doc/javaccgrm.html#prod12 for more information.